# Create list of list in go language

Tags: go

Hi I try to create slice of slice of SyntaxCommand with undetermine length

```
var result = make([][]SyntaxCommand)
result = append(result, []SyntaxCommand{})
temp := SyntaxCommand{}
result = append(result[len(result)-1], temp)
```

but i encounter error

```
missing len argument to make([][]SyntaxCommand)
temp = SyntaxCommand{}
```

How to easily make a list of list of object that is nullable? Then add new list to the end, and an object to the last list with non undetermined length?

Comment: I won't create a new answer since JimB has already answered this, but I would suggest you check out the GoBlog on slices: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to initialize the slice, don't use `make`

```
var result [][]SyntaxCommand
```

Comment: Hi I want to initialise it but without knowing the length, is that possible?

Comment: @LosCompie: a slice must have a length - you can set it to 0 if you'd like, but there's usually no reason to do so since a nil slice is valid in most cases.